# AndEngine "The Application <Application Name> has stopped unexpectedly"

Tags: andengine

No idea why this happens.
I'm simply trying to draw a sprite to the screen.
Whenever I load the android emulator and load my app, it gives:

> > The Application MyAndEngine App has stopped unexpectedly.
> >     http://pastebin.com/Q9fjSiVS

Answer (score 1):

In your code this line seems to have the problem.

```
this.mTexture = new Texture(30, 26, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

> Texture must be POWER of 2 not multiple.

In your case it should be

```
this.mTexture = new Texture(32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

Check [this](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/background-images-multiple-of-2-t1916.html) thread of AndEngine forums. Also check [Basic Structure of an AndEngine game.](http://www.andgamedev.com/archives/basic-structure-of-an-andengine-game)